# Geo Redirection. How to redirect Aus IP's from US site to AUS site

Tags: geotagging

my business partner is running an e-commerce store since 3 years in the US.
I'm starting the same in Australia ( both selling the same branded product).
He owns "name.com", I own "name.com.au"

We are trying to make things fare since he has people from Australia visiting and buying on his site.
We would like to solve this problem and redirect those customers to my site.

Consider that he ranks really well, could this be an advantage for my ranking too? ( beside having all organized, without having him dealing with Australian orders ).

What are some settings you suggest? I've done some researches and people mention  : maxmind GeoIP DDl 
or its frontend solution ( which costs some $ ) .
Any experience in regard?

Also do we need to link each other? Would this actually help my SEo at all?

What other things would you consider doing, if you were on my situation? Any other specific settings to be done? Something to be mindful of?

Thanks

Comment: Are you redirecting your US visitors from name.com.au to name.com? GEO Redirection is always bad SEO practice, because Google main IP is from US, so if they crawl your site and you redirect them to somewhere else, then Google think you're display different results to them vs real visitors, and they consider it as [cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en). You can do [multi-region SEO without redirection](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en).

Comment: Auto-redirection hurts SEO.   If you want good SEO, you can't use it.  Google crawls from all over the world.   It expects to be able to access the US site from AU and the AU site from US.   Pages will fall out of the index is Googlebot gets redirects.

Comment: If you do you IP detection you can put a notice on the site saying "You look like you are in Australia, click here to use the AU website".    Instead of IP address detection, you can also use the "Accept-Language" header which is sent by browsers.   But again, don't issue redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Ip geolocation tools can help set auto redirect visitors to correct domains based on visitors' locations. Such tools detect your visitors' location by IP. You can easily create location rules; each rule can associate location with individual domain. Regardless whichever links your visitors click on, for example, if your visitor is in Australia, he will be redirected to Australia domain.

Come to SEO. Regardless of the high ranking of US site, it's important to set hreflang tags for US and Australia sites. For multi-regional sites, it has potential risk to violate the google penalty of redundant content as US and Australia sites may have similar content. With **hreflang tags** telling google your site structure with domains targeting different markets, you could prevent penalty, and users from will only see their relevant country-level pages in search result.